# Symfony 3 - Separation of concerns?

Tags: symfony, dql

I am trying to accomplish the following:

I have a "Sprint" entity, that contains a number of Ticket entities.
Each Ticket has a TicketStatus (another entity).

Now, when rendering out the Sprint, I want to compute the sprint's progress.

Where and how do I go about this?

Intuitively I would add this in a method to my Sprint entity (something like getSprintProgress()).

But then I keep reading everywhere that you dont want to query the db in your entity class due to the separation of concerns.

How would you go about this?

Ideally I would just run a count() query on the db...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible approaches to this problem.

To start with, assuming you have defined a conventional Doctrine association between Sprint and Ticket entities then your Sprint::getProgress() is fine.  Tickets will be lazy loaded as needed.  This is actually a good place to start for something as simple as this.

You can avoid the need for lazy loading (and perhaps gain a bit of a performance improvement) by defining a query and eager loading the tickets.  If you are careful you can refine the query such that only needed portions of the tickets (the status field perhaps) are loaded.  And maybe avoid loading closed tickets completely.

Another approach is to move the progress calculator to to it's own class.  So you might have a SprintProgressCalculator::calculate($sprint) method.  Define it as a service and inject the database connection.  For rendering you can inject the calculator into a twig extension and make your own twig function.  This is the sort of approach you might take if the calculation is more involved than a simple query.

Finally, just a general observation that the ORM works well for basic CRUD type applications.  Not so much as you get involved with more business oriented operations.  So if you do have more involved calculators and business logic then you might consider dropping back to simple sql.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have implemented it like this in my Sprint entity.

```
public function getProgress() {
  $tickets = $this->tickets;
  $done_tickets = $tickets->filter(function(Ticket $ticket) {
    return $ticket->getStatus()->getName() == 'Done';
  })->count();
return ($done_tickets / $tickets->count()) * 100;
```

Let me clarify what I did here:

```
$this->tickets
```

contains an ArrayCollection. Apparently ArrayCollections have a method called filter that allows to define a closure in which I can do as I please.
*More on the filter() method [here](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/array-collection-tricks)*

In the end, I just calculate the percentage of done tickets vs the total amount of tickets in that sprint.

This does leave me wondering about 2 things:

- Coming from Laravel, where they use the Fat Models, Slim Controllers concept, this felt the most "natural". But is it really?
- What about performance? Does $this->tickets load all tickets in full? Because I actually only care about the status attached to each ticket. (the status is actually a TicketStatus entity btw).

Curious to hear other opinions on the matter.

Cheers

Comment: By default, entities are always fully loaded.  Hence the suggestion in my answer that you consider writing a custom query and only load the desired properties.  Having said that, unless your entities are truly complicated it's doubtful that you wold notice any speed improvements.  It's the sort of thing you would only optimize if you know it has become a bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Cerad. Marked it as answer. Appreciated